# How to get jpa(hibernate) query resultlist as HashMap?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hashmap

Currently I have tasked to prepare Document service for client side parser that user can view, edit, manage just allowed documents. Documentprivileges has @onetomany relationship for documents model. I have added get single privilege by document

```
  public String getDocumentPrivilege(Long documentId);
    ......
```

I also want to return HashMap (docId and privilege) via overriden method. So far I have done:

```
@Override
    public HashMap<Long, String> getDocumentPrivilege(List<Long> documentIds)
    {
        Query q = null;
        if (documentIds != null && documentIds.size()>0) {
            q = em.createQuery("select new map(d.document_id as id, d.privilege as privilege) from DocumentPrivileges d"
                    + " where d.document_id IN ?1");
            q.setParameter(1, documentIds);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<Long, String> results = (HashMap<Long, String>) q.getResultList();
            if(results != null && results.size()>0)
            return results;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 140 [select new map(d.document_id as id, d.privilege as privilege) from xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxmodel.DocumentPrivileges d where d.document_id IN :docs]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:268)
    ... 136 more
```

I have checked other examples it was quite similar. Am I following wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the map is predefined to `map<column, value>` not `map<column1value, column2value>` you have to build the map from the resultlist

Answer (score 0):

You must use setParameterList, to set the documentId list to be used with the operator 'IN' of HQL, in your query.